# Cannot convert char value to smallmoney

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

For each client we have in the `clients` table, display the `client id` and `last name`. If the client's animals have any exams last year display the average fee for the exams and the highest fee for their exams. The average and highest fees is formatted with two digits after the decimal point (use the str function). Display the string ' no exams' if there are no exams. This could be because the client has no animals, or because the animals have no exams. Order by the client id.

```
SELECT CL.cl_id AS CL_ID, CL.cl_name_last AS LastName
        ,STR(AVG(CASE WHEN YEAR(EH.ex_date) = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 THEN ED.ex_fee ELSE 'no exams' END),12,2) AS 'AverageFee'
        ,STR(MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(EH.ex_date) = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 THEN ED.ex_fee ELSE 'no exams' END),12,2) AS 'HighestFee'
    FROM vt_clients AS CL
    INNER JOIN vt_animals AS AN ON CL.cl_id = AN.cl_id
    LEFT JOIN vt_exam_headers AS EH ON AN.an_id = EH.an_id
    LEFT JOIN vt_exam_details AS ED ON EH.ex_id = ED.ex_id
    GROUP BY cl.cl_id, CL.cl_name_last
```

I get this error.

```
Msg 293, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Cannot convert char value to smallmoney. The char value has incorrect syntax.
```

Why is this?

Comment: You probably have non numeric values in your string.

Comment: Thanks! I removed "no exams" from Else and voila! but it doesn't meet the assignment's criteria which is to display "no exams" instead of what it is displaying now which is "0.00". Do you  know how I can do this?

Edit:grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform a query that has a `case` statement in it, you must make sure that for every possible input you return the same datatype, or at least datatypes that are castable to each other.

In your query, you have two clauses that attempt to perform an aggregate operation on a value that either a `smallmoney` instance or the literal `no exams`, which, of course, cannot be implicitly cast to `smallmoney`. Instead of using this literal, you should use a compatible value, e.g., `0`:

```
STR(AVG(CASE WHEN YEAR(EH.ex_date) = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 THEN ED.ex_fee ELSE 0 END),12,2) AS 'AverageFee'
```

So the entire query would be:

```
SELECT CL.cl_id AS CL_ID, CL.cl_name_last AS LastName
    ,STR(AVG(CASE WHEN YEAR(EH.ex_date) = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 THEN ED.ex_fee ELSE 0 END),12,2) AS 'AverageFee'
    ,STR(MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(EH.ex_date) = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 THEN ED.ex_fee ELSE 0 END),12,2) AS 'HighestFee'
FROM vt_clients AS CL
INNER JOIN vt_animals AS AN ON CL.cl_id = AN.cl_id
LEFT JOIN vt_exam_headers AS EH ON AN.an_id = EH.an_id
LEFT JOIN vt_exam_details AS ED ON EH.ex_id = ED.ex_id
GROUP BY cl.cl_id, CL.cl_name_last
```

Comment: Thanks! While this works, it doesn't meet the assignment criteria which is to display "no exams" instead of 0.00. Do you know how I can properly do this?

Comment: "The type of the return value is determined by the first one" - not true at all. All data types are considered and the [data type precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) is used to determine what the result type of the `CASE` expression is.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever correct. My MS-Fu seems off today.